# Splitting string into sentences using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to split a paragraph into sentences. At the moment I'm splitting by `.` which works fine but I can't seem to get it to split correctly when there's either `.` or `?` or `!`

So far my code is:

```
String[] sentences = everything.split("(?<=[a-z])\\.\\s+");
```

Thanks

Comment: How about something like this:String[] sentences = everything.split("\.|\?|\!");

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687012/split-string-into-sentences-based-on-periods - it seems relevant.

Comment: Illegal escape characters @MichaelP

Comment: @dave I had a look but I'm looking just to split it by `!` `.` and `?` . That regex command in the answers only seems to work for full stops

Comment: Sorry I forgot the parenthesis String[] sentences = everything.split("(\\.|\\?|\\!)");

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to remove `.`, `!`, `?` from the results.

```
    String[] sentences = everything.split("(?<=[a-z][!?.])\\s+");
```

Comment: I want to remove the `.` `!` and `?` from results

Comment: @ magna_nz Ok, try `"(?<=[a-z])[!?.]\\s+"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a character class, and you don't need the look behind - use a word boundary instead:

```
String[] sentences = everything.split("\\b[.!?]\\s+");
```

`"[.!?]"` means "either `.`, `!` or `?`". The word boundary `\b` requires that a word character precede the end of sentence char.