# How would I obtain only the texts of a webpage that contain necessary keyword using JSoup?

Tags: java, web, web-crawler, jsoup

I came up with something like this which didn't work out. I am trying to extract the texts that contain the keyword alone and not the entire text of the webpage just because the webpage has that keyword.

```
    String pconcat="";

for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

Document doc=Jsoup.connect(urls[i]).ignoreContentType(true).timeout(60*1000).get();

        for(int x=0;x<keyWords.length;x++){
        if(doc.body().text().toLowerCase().contains(keyWords[x].toLowerCase())){
              Elements e=doc.select("body:contains("+keyWords[x]+")");
              for(Element element : e)
                {
                pconcat+=element.text();
                System.out.println("pconcat"+pconcat);
          }     
         }
        }
       }
```

Consider example.com , if the keyword I look for is "documents" , I need the output as "This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents." and nothing else

Comment: Post example of input and output/result you are trying to find. For now we don't really know how you want to limit this result.

Comment: So since you already have text from page simply iterate over all sentences and pick the ones which contain word you are looking for. This should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2687929/1393766

Comment: Actually I am attempting to crawl a particular webpage and obtain content that match a specific keyword. More like keyword related web crawling.Your approach worked well for this page but not sure for all. Coz with example.com, it has just 2 sentence. Consider a random webpage that has links, menus,tabs, this approach mighnot seem worthy. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to lowercase the body text in order to use the [`:contains`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) selector, it is case insensitive.

> elements that contains the specified text. The search is case
>   insensitive. The text may appear in the found element, or any of its
>   descendants.

[`select()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-) is only going to return elements if it finds a match.

> elements that match the query (empty if none match)

You don't need an `if`-statement to check for "documents", just use css selectors to select any element that matches then do something with the results.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect(url)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .timeout(60*1000)
            .get();

    for (String keyword : keywords) {

        String selector = String.format(
                "p:contains(%s)", 
                keyword.toLowerCase());

        String content = doc
                .select(selector)
                .text();

        System.out.println(content);

    }
```

**Output**

> This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in
>   documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior
>   coordination or asking for permission.