# Strip off a sentence that contains a URL

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking for a way to remove a sentence that contains a URL in Java. Note that I want to remove the entire sentence and not just the URL.

I found a way to do this and it works, but I am looking for a simpler way to do this, maybe with just one RegEx?

1. Detect a sentence (can end with .?!) using BreakIterator : [Split string into sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687012/split-string-into-sentences)
2. Use a Regex to read every line and detect the pattern :
   [Detect and extract url from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713558/detect-and-extract-url-from-a-string). If found, just remove the sentence.

```
String source = "Sorry, we are closed today. Visit our website tomorrow at https://www.google.com. Thank you and have a nice day!";
iterator.setText(source);
int start = iterator.first();
int end = iterator.next();
while(end != BreakIterator.DONE){                
 if(SENT.matcher(source.substring(start,end)).find()) {                  
   source = source.substring(0, start) + source.substring(end);                  
   iterator.setText(source);
   start = iterator.first();
  }else{
    start = end;
  }
  end = iterator.next();
}
System.out.println(source);

This prints : Sorry, we are closed today. Thank you and have a nice day!
```

Comment: A *particular* URL, or *any* URL?

Comment: Any URL. Can start with http/https/www/ftp, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"(?<=^|[?!.])[^?!.]+" + urlRegex + ".*?(?:$|[?!.])"
```

This will match each whole sentence whose part matches `urlRegex`, according to your definition of a sentence; you can use `replaceAll` to get rid of them. (There are many URL regexes around, and you didn't specify which one you were using, so I left the exact definition of URL to you.)

Comment: This is nice, it worked! Just curious, what does the "?<=^" indicate?

Comment: (?<=...) is a positive lookbehind zero-width assertion ("there has to be ... just before, but don't include it into the match"). `^` is start of string (or line if you use `Pattern.MULTILINE`). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> It'd be best to break/split our sentences first, prior to having it passed through an expression.

Then, this expression might simply return only those lines (sentences) that do not have a URL,

```
^(?!.*https?[^\s]+.*).*$
```

Here, we'd be defining a URL as `https?[^\s]+`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z8misk/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(?!.*https?[^\\s]+.*).*$";
final String string = "Sorry, we are closed today. Visit our website tomorrow at https://www.google.com. Thank you and have a nice day!\n\n"
     + "Sorry, we are closed today. Visit our website tomorrow at. Thank you and have a nice day!\n\n"
     + "Sorry, we are closed today. Visit our website tomorrow at https://www.goog. Thank you and have a nice day!\n";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: That regex says absolutely nothing about sentences. It matches _lines_ that contain a URL.

Comment: I'd thought splitting them and stitching them up too, but that was something I was trying to avoid in general. This is a good alternate though. thanks!